# Pruning before running convex hull algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull, pruning

I have to form a Convex Hull from large amount of points and I came across [this](http://mindthenerd.blogspot.com/2012/05/fastest-convex-hull-algorithm-ever.html) article. Whole process of pruning is described and well explained, except for one part.

I don't know what this part means and how to convert it to code:

> Since the space is two-dimensional, each point has two coordinates, x > and y. Every time we read a new point, we compute the following 4 > points:
>
> A = (Ax, Ay) which maximizes x-y
> B = (Bx, Xy) which maximizes x+y
> C = (Cx, Cy) which minimizes x-y
> D = (Dx, Dy) which minimizes x+y

Can anyone help me to calculate points A,B,C,D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not so much *calculating* the points, you're selecting them from your input data:

- `A` is the point in your input data where the value of `x-y` is larger than any other input data point.
- `B` is the point in your input data where the value of `x+y` is larger than any other input data point.
- `C` is the point in your input data where the value of `x-y` is smaller than any other input data point.
- `D` is the point in your input data where the value of `x+y` is smaller than any other input data point.